# Why does processes take different time to execute in multi-processing?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am running a programm that processes 3 laks row dataframe using multi-processing. I do this over 64 core VM using 62 processes created using multiprocess.process in python. Each process is fed 4900 rows.

Oddly, process takes different time to finish. first process finished the task in 15 minutes while last one took more than 70. Below is code block for multi-processing that I've used.

```
import multiprocessing

# define dataframe here
data_thread = data
uid = "final"   ### make sure to change uid

batch_size = 4900
counter = 0
datalen = len(data_thread)
Flag = True
processes = []

while(Flag):
    start = counter*batch_size
    end = min(datalen, start+batch_size)
    if end>=datalen:
        Flag = False

    indices.append((start, end))
    data_split = data_thread.iloc[start:end]
    threadName = "process_"+str(counter)
    processes.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=process, args = (data_split, uid, threadName, start, end, )))
    counter = counter+1

startCount = 0
while(startCount<len(processes)):
    t = processes[startCount]
    try:
        t.start()
    except:
        print("Error encountered while starting the process_%lf: %s"%(startCount, str(indices[startCount])))
    print("Started: process_" + str(startCount))
    startCount = startCount + 1

endCount = 0
while(endCount<len(processes)):
    t = processes[endCount]
    t.join()
    print("Joined: process_" + str(endCount))
    endCount = endCount + 1
```

Comment: In general, timing depends on I/O and other running processes. Anything that creates competition for resources is going to mess with timing. No idea in your particular case though.

Comment: Are there other users/processes on the same machine that take up CPU time? How guaranteed is it that the actual process always takes the same amount of time for different input?

Comment: Also, what's your data and process look like? Maybe you have some pathological data that just takes that long to process. It's literally impossible to say without additional information.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm trying to process a pandas dataframe. I pass a slice of dataframe and then apply some operations on each row using a for loop. Operations include regexp search in nested if-else statement. Each process, once finishes, writes its output to a pickel file and joins. Input to all processes are almost identical. What makes me curious is some processes took about 2 hrs to finish. I'm still running and last process is yet to finish, it's more than 2 hrs.

Comment: @9769953 No. I've dedicated this instance for this specific purspose only. I/O operations are minimal and are same for all processes i.e. to write a file once finished, report time it took to finish.

Comment: You're applying regex and running for loops using pandas? That may be a big part of the problem. Unless you show what you are actually doing, how do you expect someone to point and say "here is the bottleneck"?